# Python BeautifulSoup print from just table cell

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Am new to Beautiful Soup. I'm trying to get a python script that will scrape a webpage, and then print a condensed list. So far I have:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'https://shropshire.gov.uk/waste/binday/index.jsc?p=0&go=Go&designation=3&postcode=sy3+9jt&gobutton=Go'
content = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')

current = soup.find("div", {"class": "maxi calendar_month"})

print(current.text)
```

My questions are:

1. How do I get B/S to read from only the table cells i.e.  not  in HTML?
2. How do I condense this list to remove the line breaks?

I would ideally like to store the output as a python Dictionary

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what problem you are facing, you want your data to be structured that is clear, but what is the ideal output you are looking for ? So far I can see the implementation is correct but what you are not able to do ?

Comment: Hi, ideal output would by a dictionary or similar that is simply dict { 1: "Recycling", 2: "", 3: "Garden Waste" } etc so taking the values from only the cells in the table (not header) and condense it into a dictionary

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, your approach was correct but the execution was not there. To make it simpler let's break this down into small steps:

1. Get the table you want to scrape
2. If it is a table, then get each rows of the table as list
3. Once we have rows, we will fetch each individual cell and put it in dictionary

   ```
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
   import requests

   main_data = {}
   URL = 'https://shropshire.gov.uk/waste/binday/index.jsc?p=0&go=Go&designation=3&postcode=sy3+9jt&gobutton=Go'
   content = requests.get(URL)

   soup = BeautifulSoup(content.text, 'html.parser')

   table = soup.find("table")
   rows = table.find_all("tr", {"class": ""})

   for row in rows:
       data_list = row.find_all("td")
       for data in data_list:
           is_valid = data.find("div")
           if is_valid:
               tags = [tag.text.strip() for tag in data.find_all("span")]
               date = data.find("div").text.strip()
               main_data[date] = tags

   print(main_data)
   ```

Output:

```
{'1': [], '2': [], '3': [], '4': ['Rubbish'], '5': [], '6': [], '7': [], '8': [], '9': [], '10': [], '11': ['Garden waste', 'Recycling boxes'], '12': [], '13': [], '14': [], '15': [], '16': [], '17': [], '18': ['Rubbish'], '19': [], '20': [], '21': [], '22': [], '23': [], '24': [], '25': ['Garden waste', 'Recycling boxes'], '26': [], '27': [], '28': [], '29': [], '30': []}
```

I hope you understood what I did, you can go ahead with this and increment on top of it to improve or make it more stable

Comment: Super useful thank you! I think I was trying to run before I could walk but all good to keep the brain going

Answer (score 0):

The `<div class="maxi calendar_month">` contains an HTML `<table>`, and that table contains rows (`<tr>`), and each row contains columns (`td`). Each columns contains two adjacent divs, the first contains just the number representing the day of the month, the second div looks either like this: `<div class="a_collection">` or `<div class="two_collection">`, depending on whether there is one or more than one line in a given cell as far as I can tell. This second div is present for all cells, even the ones that don't have any content in them, like "rubbish" or "garden waste". If such content is present, however, this div contains some other divs, and the text you're after is located in one of them. Here's what I came up with:

```
def main():

    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests

    url = "https://shropshire.gov.uk/waste/binday/index.jsc?p=0&go=Go&designation=3&postcode=sy3+9jt&gobutton=Go"

    response = requests.get(url)
    response.raise_for_status()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    def get_table_as_dict(table):
        date_div = table.select_one("tr.month")
        month = date_div.select_one("th").find(text=True).strip().lower()
        year = date_div.select_one("span.year").get_text(strip=True)
        yield "month", month
        yield "year", year

        def get_days():
            for cell in table.select("td:not(.empty)"):
                day_number = cell.select_one("div:nth-child(1)").get_text(strip=True)
                content_divs = cell.select_one("div:nth-child(2) ").select("div:not([class*=\"print\"])")
                if content_divs:
                    content = ", ".join(text for text in [content_div.find(text=True).strip() for content_div in content_divs])
                else:
                    content = ""
                yield day_number, content
        yield "days", dict(get_days())

    for table in soup.findAll("table"):
        print(dict(get_table_as_dict(table)))

    return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    sys.exit(main())
```

Output:

```
{'month': 'june', 'year': '2020', 'days': {'1': '', '2': '', '3': '', '4': 'Rubbish', '5': '', '6': '', '7': '', '8': '', '9': '', '10': '', '11': 'Garden waste, Recycling boxes', '12': '', '13': '', '14': '', '15': '', '16': '', '17': '', '18': 'Rubbish', '19': '', '20': '', '21': '', '22': '', '23': '', '24': '', '25': 'Garden waste, Recycling boxes', '26': '', '27': '', '28': '', '29': '', '30': ''}}
{'month': 'july', 'year': '2020', 'days': {'2': 'Rubbish', '9': 'Garden waste, Recycling boxes', '16': 'Rubbish', '23': 'Garden waste, Recycling boxes', '30': 'Rubbish'}}
{'month': 'august', 'year': '2020', 'days': {'6': 'Garden waste, Recycling boxes', '13': 'Rubbish', '20': 'Garden waste, Recycling boxes', '27': 'Rubbish'}}
>>>
```

`get_table_as_dict` is a generator that yields key-value pairs, so that later you can consume and collapse the generator to create an entire dictionary. We do this in a loop that iterates over all the tables in the HTML, so that in the end we have three dictionaries, one for each calendar table / month on the page.

`get_days` is also a generator that yields key-value pairs. It yields all of its contents in the third and final yield of `get_table_as_dict`. Basically, we iterate through all the cells in the current table using a CSS-selector - iterate over all `td` elements whose class is not "empty" (the tables sometimes have `td`s with `class="empty"` to pad the table with more cells after the last day of the month, and these cells we don't want. Rather than specifying the cells we do want, we specify the ones we don't want, because the ones we want are cells that land on weekdays, which have no class, and cells that land on weekends, which have `class="weekend"`).

Once we have the current valid cell, we get the first, immediate child div, and get only the immediate text it contains, and strip it - this is the day number as a string.

Then, we create a list of `content_divs`. These represent the potential divs that could exist within a cell. Some cells have no content, some cells have one relevant item in them (for example, "rubbish"), and some divs even have two relevant items in them ("Garden waste" and "Recycling boxes"). We get these divs by selecting the second div child of the current cell, and from that div we select all child divs whose class does not contain the substring "print" (for whatever reason, these annoying redundant divs are there, but we are not interested in them).

Comment: Really helpful, thank you so much! I'm guessing to limit to just the current month table is not as simple as remove the 'all' from  "  for table in soup.findAll("table"):   "?

Comment: @AdamDavies Glad it's helpful. Removing the "all" wouldn't cut it, but if you only want  the first table, it's still a pretty simply change to make. One way of doing it would be to add a `break` statement in the body of the loop, so that the loop terminates prematurely after the very first iteration - what would make more sense though, is to get rid of the loop altogether, and simply say `print(dict(get_table_as_dict(soup.find("table"))))`

Comment: I'll go do some more playing but this is a phenomenal start, thanks. Final aim for this project is to illuminate a smart lamp based on what bins go out tomorrow - lockdown boredom hitting hard!